# Can Phalcon support other NoSQL?

Tags: couchbase, phalcon

I love Phalcon, but it does not come with Couchbase whereas Couchbase provides ODM and SDKs (Dlls for XAMPP / WAMPP) for PHP. Can you please compile Phalcon with Couchbase SDKs / ODM ?

I am looking for Couchbase because so far Couchbase is the best of all NoSQL servers I have worked with. It supports distributive memcache-compatible in-memory Key-Value store as well as Document Store. Also, it allows N1QL (SQL-like Data Query language), Eventing Services using JavaScript and much more. It supports Full-Text Search with Fuzzy-Search as optional parameter. It is lightning fast and features-rich as compared to other NoSQL. It also offers Enterprise version with Enterprise-level support. Note that Doctrine-2 supports Couchbase, but I want it with Phalcon, not with any thick-layered ORM.

Comment: Which Falcon are you asking about? Your question is currently tagged with `falcon` (programming language) and `falconframework`  (Python cloud API) but I suspect you may have intended `phalcon` (PHP framework) given mention of Doctrine. Your current question is also feedback for the developers, so is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as a programming question for StackOverflow. You should share that feedback directly with the relevant developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a suggestion for the original framework developers rather than a programming question.

Comment: Mongo has minimal support within Phalcon: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/cache/backend/mongo.zep And meant to be paired with Incubator: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter Toss in a New Feature request to incubator, and we can give it a trial run. I don't think we'll be adding support directly to cphalcon for it for reasons similar to the current plan to remove Beanstalkd from cphalcon in version 4.0.0 https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/13364